# Closest partial Fourier Polynomial to an integrable periodic function

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

This is a question from an exam I faild and I would really like to
know how to solve it:

Let $J\subset\mathbb{Z}$ be a finite set and let $E_{J}=\text{Span}\left\{ e_{n}(x)\mid n\in J\right\} $
where $e_{n}(x)=e^{inx}$.

Now let $f\in R(\mathbb{T})$ (Means that $f$ is integrable and periodic
over $\left[0,2\pi\right]$), and let $g\in E_{J}$ be that function
such that:
$$
\left\Vert f-g\right\Vert =\inf\left\{ \left\Vert f-h\right\Vert \mid h\in E_{J}\right\} 
$$

Prove that 
$$
g=\sum_{n\in J}\hat{f}(n)e_{n}
$$

Just for clarification:

$\left\Vert \right\Vert $ is the norm of the inner product defined
by $\left\langle f,g\right\rangle =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$,
and $\hat{f}(n)$ is the $n$'th Fourier Coefficient that is $\hat{f}(n)=\left\langle f,e_{n}\right\rangle =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx$.

This is what I know so far:

Let $N=\max\left\{ \left|n\right|\mid n\in J\right\} $, and let $S_{N}f=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)e_{n}$.
Now I already know that
$$
\left\Vert f-S_{N}f\right\Vert =\inf\left\{ \left\Vert f-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}a_{n}e_{n}\right\Vert \mid a_{n}\in\mathbb{C}\right\} 
$$

That is the closest Trigonometric Polynomial of rank $\leq N$ to $f$ by norm. Also we can split $S_{N}f$ by $S_{N}f=\sum_{n\in J}\hat{f}(n)e_{n}+\sum_{n\notin J}\hat{f}(n)e_{n}$.

How can I continue?

Comment: With $e_n(x)=  \frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ the $\{e_n\}$ are an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,2\pi])$. Thus for $f \in L^2([0,2\pi])$ you obtain 
$$ 
\|f - \sum_{n \in J} a_n e_n\|^2 = \|\sum_{n \in J} (\langle f,e_n \rangle -a_n) e_n+ \sum_{n \not \in J}\langle f,e_n \rangle e_n\|^2 \\=\sum_{n \in J} |\langle f,e_n \rangle-a_n |^2+ \sum_{n \not\in J} |\langle f,e_n \rangle |^2 \ge \sum_{n \not\in J} |\langle f,e_n \rangle |^2$$

Comment: Ok yes, and how can that help me?

Comment: Minimizing $\sum_{n \in J} |\langle f,e_n \rangle-a_n |^2$ over $a$ is not hard..